# Where to position fill color in a turtle graphic function in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function, turtle-graphics

I'm practicing functions with Think like a Computer Scientist and I wanted to 
make a variation in an exercise whose purpose is to draw an octagon. I want the octagon to be filled with a specific color but I'm not sure where to put the code for the color fill. It was working fine with just the pen color. This is what I did but the result is a black color for both the outside and the inside of the octagon:

```
import turtle

wn =turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("yellow")


def drawOctagon(t, sz,ang):
"""Make turtle t draw an octagon of size sz with angle ang"""

    for i in range(8):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(ang)


t = turtle.Turtle()        
sz = 70
ang = 360/8
t.color("white,white")
t.begin_fill()
drawOctagon(t,sz, ang)
t.end_fill()
wn.exitonclick()
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You basically have it.  Simply change this line:

```
t.color("white,white")
```

to instead read:

```
t.color("white", "white")
```

Though white on yellow is awfully hard to look at!  Below is my rework of your code with the above fix and some style changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

my_size = 70
my_angle = 360 / 8

def drawPolygon(turtle, size, angle):
    """ Make 'turtle' draw a polygon of 'size' with 'angle' """

    for _ in range(int(360 / angle)):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(angle)

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor("yellow")

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.color("white", "white")

yertle.begin_fill()
drawPolygon(yertle, my_size, my_angle)
yertle.end_fill()

wn.exitonclick()
```

It didn't make sense to me to pass an angle into a routine named `drawOctagon()`, since it should already know the angle, so I generalized it to be `drawPolygon()` instead.  You can change the denominator in the `my_angle` calculation to make a hexagon, etc.